# Why is arccos $\left(\frac{-x}{r}\right)$ = 180° - arccos $\left(\frac{x}{r}\right)$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

When calculating the argument of a complex number,

I use the formula φ = arccos $\left(\frac{x}{r}\right)$ if the complex number is in the first or second quadrant.

Why is the statement arccos $\left(\frac{-x}{r}\right)$ = 180° - arccos $\left(\frac{x}{r}\right)$ true?

How do I prove / show this?

Thank you for any input.

Comment: This formula follows directly from the properties of the cosine function. Just plot the cosine, and everything should be clear.

Answer (score 1):

By definition $\arccos x$ is defined for $x\in[-1,1]$ and is bijective with range $[0,\pi]$, therefore, assuming $|x|\le r$ we have

$$\theta=\arccos(x/r)\iff \pi-\theta=\arccos(-x/r)$$

that is

$$\arccos(-x/r)=\pi -\arccos(x/r)$$

Answer (score 1):

Imagine two lines that intersect at a point.  Take distance $x$ in each direction on one of them, and distance $r$ is each
direction on the other.  Draw perpendiculars to the $x$ line, to give us two right triangles.

[image: picture]

In the picture, angle $\alpha$ is $\arccos\frac{x}{r}$ and
angle $\beta$ is $\arccos\frac{-x}{r}$.
So $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are **supplementary angles**:
that is, their sum is $180$ degrees.